# Getting the coordinates of a point on section

Tags: coordinate-systems

What is the endpoint $P(x,y)$ of a line segment , if I know its starting point: $C(x(1), y(1))$, the gradient $G$, and its length $L$?

Comment: @AlexM. This question is specifically posed in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (By the way, the "gradient" here is what others may call "slope").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

$$(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=L^2$$

and $$G=\dfrac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}$$

Comment: $$\dfrac{x-x_1}1=\dfrac{y-y_1}G$$  $$=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}{1^2+G^2}}=\pm\dfrac L{\sqrt{1+G^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
D = C + L (G/\lVert G\rVert)
$$
where 
$$
\lVert G\rVert= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^2 G_i^2}
$$
is the length of $G$.

Comment: But G is the gradient, how can it have a length?

Comment: Maybe we mean different things? A gradient of a curve $u$ is the vector $(\partial_x u, \partial_y u)$.

Comment: Ok, sorry i had it wrong, but what is D and C?

Comment: $C$ is the start point you gave in your question, $D$ is the end point of the segment $CD$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it's clear now.